# Getting Result out of a Task

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have an asynchronous function that returns the result of an App Store query (was the query successful or not displayed in an alert). I am having trouble getting the result out of the task--**Cannot find 'result' in scope**. If I move *let gotTitle = result ? "Success" : "The Request Failed"* to within the task I see the warning "Initialization of immutable value 'gotTitle' was never used".

The Apple documentation on Task talks about using value or result to get data out of a task, but it isn't clear on how to do that. I have also stepped through the code with the debugger. It is showing correctly result = true and gotTitle = Success within the task.

```
struct TestAlert: View {

    var gotTitle: String = ""

    @State private var presentAlert = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                Task {

                    let result = await restore()
                    print (result)
                    
                }
                let gotTitle = result ? "Success" : "The Request Failed"
                print(gotTitle)
            }) {
                Text("Restore Purchase")
            }
        }
        .alert(gotTitle, isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {

        })

    }
    func restore() async -> Bool {

            return ((try? await AppStore.sync()) != nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you put all the logic behind an `ObservableObject`, like [@Jon Shier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272952/jon-shier) suggested, and have a `@Published` variable with the result you get from the `restore` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> I am having trouble getting the result out of the task
>
> > Cannot find 'result' in scope.

Yes, as presented in your question, `result` is a local variable inside the task, so you can't refer to it outside of the `Task` (unless you save it, or the title string, in a property of the `struct`).

> If I move let gotTitle = result ? "Success" : "The Request Failed" to within the task I see the warning "Initialization of immutable value 'gotTitle' was never used".

Yes, you have defined `gotTitle` to be a local variable that just happens to have the same name as the property of the same name.

---

So, before I go to the solution, let's make a few observations so we understand what is going on. The key issue is that a `Task` with an `await` inside it runs *asynchronously.* Consider:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            Task {
                print(Date(), "started task")
                let result = await restore()
                let gotTitle = result ? "Success" : "The Request Failed"  // a local variable; we'll fix this in the next example
                print(Date(), "task finished", gotTitle)
            }
            print(Date(), "after task submitted")
        }) {
            Text("Restore Purchase")
        }
    }
    .alert(gotTitle, isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: { })
}
```

Note that I have moved the `let gotTitle` *inside* the `Task` block. You can’t reference `result` outside of this block of code.

Anyway, when you tap on the button, you will see the following in the console:

```
2022-04-18 00:38:03 +0000 after task submitted
2022-04-18 00:38:03 +0000 started task
2022-04-18 00:38:06 +0000 task finished Success
```

Note the sequence of events:

- “started task” showed up *after* “after task submitted”
- “task finished” showed up seconds after “started task”

Hopefully, this illustrates why it makes no sense to refer to `result` where the printing of “after task submitted” is taking place. You haven’t even gotten to the declaration/assignment of `result` by that point.

So, the moral of the story is that if you want something updated after the asynchronous task, it needs to be immediately after the `await` line, inside the `Task` (or whatever context it is in). If you put it outside of the `Task`, it means that it won’t wait for the asynchronous `Task` to finish.

---

So, how would you access the result out of the `Task` block. You would save it to an `ObservedProperty` (which, coincidentally, helps separate the business logic from the view):

```swift
struct TestAlert: View {
    @ObservedObject var restoreRequest = AppStoreRestoreRequest()
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                Task {
                    await restoreRequest.restore()
                    isPresented = true
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Restore Purchase")
            }
        }
        .alert(restoreRequest.state.title, isPresented: $isPresented, actions: { })
    }
}

class AppStoreRestoreRequest: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: State = .notDetermined

    func restore() async {
        let result = (try? await AppStore.sync()) != nil
        state = result ? .success : .failure
    }
}

extension AppStoreRestoreRequest {
    enum State {
        case notDetermined
        case success
        case failure
    }
}

extension AppStoreRestoreRequest.State {
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .notDetermined: return "Not determined."
        case .success:       return "Success."
        case .failure:       return "The request failed."
        }
    }
}
```

So, the performance of the request (and the current state) is pulled out of the view and the state of the request is captured in the `AppStoreRestoreRequest`.

Comment: Thanks Rob for taking the time to walk me through an interaction with a task!

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not recommended you combine view and business logic like this (SwiftUI prefers you put that behind an `ObservableObject` of some kind), you can use the `Task` just like a completion handler by putting your completion work inside it.

```swift
Task { @MainActor in // SwiftUI requires state is updated on the main queue.
  // Perform async work.
  // Update state.
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon: With your sample code I still get 'cannot find result in scope'. I also tried moving restore() into my store class with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed variant

```
struct TestAlert: View {

    @State var gotTitle: String = ""          // << state !!
    @State private var presentAlert = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                Task {

                    let result = await restore()
                    print (result)
                    await MainActor.run {     // << update on Main !!
                        gotTitle = result ? "Success" : "The Request Failed"
                        print(gotTitle)
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Restore Purchase")
            }
        }
        .alert(gotTitle, isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {

        })

    }
    func restore() async -> Bool {
        return ((try? await AppStore.sync()) != nil)
    }
}
```